# refactoring the following code to use jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code that adds event listeners that were not written with jQuery.

```
pic1.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd",
    function(){
        pic1.className="down";
        pic1.style.zIndex=picclick;
        },true);
pic1.addEventListener("oTransitionEnd",
    function(){
        pic1.className="down";
        pic1.style.zIndex=picclick;
        },true);
pic1.addEventListener("transitionEnd",
    function(){
        pic1.className="down";
        pic1.style.zIndex=picclick;
        },true);
```

I want to now add the eventListeners with jQuery, and maintain the same functionality. Ideas on what this should look like?

Here's a sketch of what I'm doing...
http://jsdo.it/dbwest/4rqo

Comment: I'm not trying to be snarky, but what have you tried to do so far (i.e. in Jquery?). Also, what do you mean by "event listeners that wasn't written without jQuery" you can use jQuery's ``bind`` or ``on``  handlers to do this. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11284204/1048479) SO post

Comment: Why are you repeating the same code 3 times?

Comment: Here you go: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/.

Comment: @Nick Don't worry about being snarky, and you guys are asking good questions. I forked the project on a site kind of like jsfiddle, jsdo.it, and I'm trying to learn. @Eugene, I seriously don't know why the previous author repeated himself that way, I supposed because of the differences between `webkitTransitionEnd` `oTransitionEnd` and `transitionEnd`.

Comment: @David: You could define the event handler *once* (`function handler() { this.className = ... ; }` and then reuse it: `pic1.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', handler); pic1.addEventListener('oTransitionEnd', handler); ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

event listeners can be replaced in jquery with `.on` or `.bind` statements:

```
var pic1 = $('yourElementOrClass');

pic1.on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function(){
    $(this).addClass('down').css('z-index', picclick);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to bind all 3 events in one command like below. I've also included the jQuery equivalents of setting the class and zindex.

```
$(pic1).bind('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function(){
    $(this).attr('class','down').css('z-index', picclick);
});
```

or

```
$(pic1).on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function(){
    $(this).attr('class','down').css('z-index', picclick);
});
```

Comment: ``.attr('class')`` is a bad practice

Comment: @Kosmetika: Never heard that it is bad practice. It's certainly a quick way to "reset" the classes to the value, without all the checking whether the class exists or not.

Comment: @Kosmetika - I'm well aware of addClass/removeClass. Using attr() is a closer equivalent for what is being done in the original question though.

Comment: @FelixKling you can simply use $('.class'), that's why selectors exist..

Comment: @Kosmetika that's entirely different functionality. This needs to *set* the class, not filter by it.

Comment: @Kosmetika: `$('.class')` *selects* elements with class `class`. `element.attr('class', 'foo')` sets the `class` attribute of `element` to `foo`. Two totally different things.

Comment: yeah, sorry guys, didn't notice this in question's code

Comment: then ``attr`` is ok, but ``add/toggle/removeClass`` is more natural way

Comment: would you use .addClass() instead @Kosmetika?

Comment: @DavidWest yeah sure, checkout my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16904123/2117550

Comment: @Kosmetika: Sure. Though the exact equivalent to the original code would be `$(this).removeClass().addClass('down');`. Maybe `.removeClass()` is not needed, but we don't know. So why remove and then add if you can just overwrite :)

Comment: @FelixKling we don't know when he wants to ``removeClass`` but ``attr`` is not good, because he can have one more needed classes on this element

Comment: @DavidWest please accept my latest answer if it suites your needs

Comment: @Kosmetika: I'm going by the original code. And `pic1.className="down";` overwrites existing classes. I assume that's what the OP wants, otherwise, why would they use it? No need to speculate otherwise here.

Comment: @FelixKling http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lndswgG1Np1qch7pn.jpg

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted? The answer is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you've done enough research for this question, but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt. jQuery has `.on`, which is the recommended way to bind events. Also it has a shortcut for exactly this situation:

```
$(pic1).on("webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd transitionEnd",
function(){
    pic1.className="down";
    pic1.style.zIndex=picclick;
});
```

Having all the events in one like this means you can avoid duplicating code.